# While configuring the Python Amazon Product API, it gives unknown locale error for 'locale'='in'

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am new to the Amazon Product API. I have installed the Python Amazon Product API. I am trying to initialise the Amazon API with my access no, secret key and affiliate tag, and locale.  I am using `'locale' : 'in'`. It gives unknown locale error. With other locale like "us", or "uk", it does not give an error. Can some one please help me out.

My code:

```
import amazonproduct

config = {

    'access_key': '***************',
    'secret_key': '**************************',
    'associate_tag': '************',
    'locale': 'in'
}

api = amazonproduct.API(cfg=config)
```

The error is:

```
UnknownLocale                            
 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-6af6386efe00> in <module>()

 5     'locale': 'in'      
6 }

----> 7 api = amazonproduct.API(cfg=config)


/Users/niharsuryawanshi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amazonproduct/api.pyc in __init__(self, access_key_id, secret_access_key, locale, associate_tag, processor, cfg)

153             self.host = HOSTS[self.locale]

154         except KeyError:

--> 155             raise UnknownLocale(locale)

156 

157         # GAE does not allow timeouts to be specified manually


UnknownLocale: None
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still under work:
https://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api/issues/58/dose-this-lib-support-indian-amazon-also

While the fix is trivial, a patch won't be officually accepted until the library's tests have been adjusted as well.